# Resignation and new project at the same time

Tags: resignation

Few weeks back, I had an interview with a company. They called me again for the second round interview and I think the result is positive. HR was also saying that they will mail me the confirmation letter very soon. I am 99% sure that I am selected. Salary has also been discussed. Here in my current company, I was planning that I will mail my resignation letter when I receive the confirmation mail from HR.

But today in the meeting my manager was discussing about a new project which they will assign me. But as I am planning to leave the company so definitely I will not accept the project but because I have not received the confirmation from HR, so I am confused. Should I tell my manager about my resignation before accepting the project or should I wait for their confirmation and add delay for the new project in my current company. If I tell my manager about my resignation and due to any reasons HR didn't send me the confirmation, then I guess it'll be a problem. How to handle this situation

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Yes thank you. I'll discuss it first and then mail.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I am 99% sure that I am selected. Salary has also been discussed.

The goal of HR is to make sure that anybody that they **may** select is 99% sure they will get an offer. They do this so they will not lose potential employees because they think they have no chance.

Even if you get an offer you don't know the exact salary, the benefits or the starting date.

Telling them is a bad idea.

Telling the current company that you are almost out the door, lets them know that you will be leaving soon. That is exactly how they will treat you as long as you remain. Say goodbye to new projects, new training. If anybody needs to be let go for budget reasons you will be the one.

Of course if you get the new job your time in purgatory will be short. But if you don't take the job or if there never is an offer....

Comment: Why this answer has been downvoted.? It looks good to me.

Comment: @SAndrew - We have a couple of curmudgeons around here.  Really good answers always have 2 or 3 downvotes.  It's how you know you're getting under the skin of someone who really needs to be learning from what's being said.  This answer is in that category.

Answer (score 10):

You should almost never turn in a resignation without a job offer in hand. You never know what could happen between the time of your last interview, and their final decision. They could interview another person, who is an even better fit than you, or they could lose funding for the position/project.

Answer (score 1):

Proceed as normal with your current company.  Under no circumstances tell them anything about the new offer until if/when your have a signed offer from newco.  That way if the new offer does not happen you have not ruined the relationship with your current employer.

Having a new project with currentco should not be a determining factor.  After you  resign, give the standard two weeks notice and work with your current manager on a transition.  Yes this could place your current company in a bind.  That you can't control.  Be professional.

Comment: Bingo.  I've had projects cut, companies close & been fired - never once have I been given advance notice.  Giving them two weeks is *already*  more respect than they give you.

Answer (score 0):

I would not mention the role to your current employer. You never know what is going on behind the scenes at the other company. Could be budget problems, organizational changes, etc. Stuff the HR people may not even be attuned to. If you think the offer is eminent then it shouldn't be too hard to stall a day or so. If not, then just accept the project as if you're going to start and when you have the other offer in hand you can explain it. If the job falls through then you haven't shirked your duties. If you go you'll have barely started the project anyways so you won't leave them that high and dry anyways. You should be loyal and fair to your company, but not to the point where it puts your career progression at risk.